# How to use javascript with selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to execute a `javascript` using python selenium. I am basically trying to set the value using `execute.script` but somehow is it not doing anything. I want to edit the street address as you see below

```
execute_script(driver, """var element = document.getElementsByClassName('input[ng-model="formData.address.address1"]'); element.value = '328 91st Street'; """)
```

[image]

Could anyone tell me what's the issue here? I am not getting an error also

Comment: In case you don't know.... `getElementsByClassName` will return you an array.... so you must do element[0] (if you want the first element)

Comment: is there any way I can print out the element array? I am getting an error `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: You can debug like `console.log(element)` and you will get the array...

Comment: I just updated the answer... you should use `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is almost good to go...

`execute_script(driver, """var element = document.getElementsByClassName('input[ng-model="formData.address.address1"]'); element.value = '328 91st Street'; """)`

Just remember that `getElementsByClassName` will return an array...

And I guess you should use **`querySelector`** or **`querySelectorAll`** function...

```
// will select just one element 
var element = document.querySelector('input[ng-model="formData.address.address1"]'); 

// will select all elements
var element = document.querySelectorAll('input[ng-model="formData.address.address1"]');
```

`getElementsByClassName` you should inform a class... (I think it's hard to have a class like: `ng-model="formData.address.address1"`)

#### Using `querySelector`

> `var element = document.querySelector('input[ng-model="formData.address.address1"]');` 
> `element.value = '328 91st Street';//Work!!!`

#### In case you want to iterate in these NodeLists with `querySelectorAll`

Basically,

> `var element = document.querySelectorAll('input[ng-model="formData.address.address1"]');` 
> `element.value = '328 91st Street';//WON'T WORK`

Do instead:

> `var element = document.querySelectorAll('input[ng-model="formData.address.address1"]');` 
> `element[0].value = '328 91st Street'; // change the value for the first element`
>
> ```
> for(int i = 0 ;i<element.length;i++){ //change all elements
>    element[i].value =  '328 91st Street';
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

There is a more robust way of doing it - locating the element with selenium using a CSS selector and passing the `WebElement` as well as a value into the script as an argument:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[ng-model="formData.address.address1"]')
value = '328 91st Street'

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'arguments[1]';", elm, value)
```

---

Note that in your code, you have 2 major problems:

- you are passing a CSS selector into the `getElementsByClassName()` call  - instead, it expects you to pass a class name as a string
- `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements and not a single element